# Filtering Signals via Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

Please forgive the noob pine question, but I wouldn't know where to find this answer in the manual:

I'd like to filter Long and Short signals using 2 corresponding signal conditions.

Let's say the filtering signals are "LongFilter" and "ShortFilter." After the last LongFilter signal I'd like to only show Long signals, as with with Short signals after ShortFilter signals.

How do I get the Filter signal condition to remain constant after the bar that triggered it has passed?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you explain further and maybe add a code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use var declared bool variables to track the state of longFilter or shortFilter conditions, which wont reset until the next opposite filter signal occurs.

```
var bool longFilter = na
var bool shortFilter = na

if myLongFilterCondition
    longFilter := true
    shortFilter := false
else if myshortFilterCondition
    longFilter := false
    shortFilter := true

enterLong = longFilter and myLongEntryConditions
enterShort = shortFilter and myShortEntryConditions
```